# CircleCI cannot find gradle. Error: ./gradlew: No such file or directory

Tags: java, gradle, circleci-2.0, circleci-workflows, circleci-orb

I am working on a project that is developed with Java & Gradle.
I want to make it work with CircleCi. I am using the simple CircleCi configuration:

```
version: 2.1

orbs: 
  gradle: circleci/gradle@2.2.0

workflows:
  checkout-build-test:
    jobs:
      - gradle/test
```

However, whenever I push the code, I am getting the following error:
[./gradlew: No such file or directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l09KF.png)

The thing is that the root folder of Gradle is not the same as CircleCi. All the java code is stored in a sub folder and not in the main folder.
Usually, the source code and the CircleCi folders are stored at the same folder's level. How can I configure CircleCi to run Gradle from a different folder which is not the main?

Comment: Does your repo contain `gradlew` in its root directory? Does this example project answer your question: https://github.com/CircleCI-Public/circleci-demo-java-spring

Comment: No, I don't. This is exactly the thing, it is located on a sub folder named "src-code". So I basically needs to set CircleCi to find Gradle on a different folder other than the default one

Comment: There is a part in the example yml where they change directory: Maybe you need to specify build steps manually? https://github.com/CircleCI-Public/circleci-demo-java-spring/blob/master/.circleci/config.yml#L49-L62

Comment: I need to be able to do it without defining jobs, since jobs requires using dockers. And in my project they don't want to use a docker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to this problem. which is:

```
version: 2.1

orbs: 
  gradle: circleci/gradle@2.2.0

workflows:
  checkout-build-test:
    jobs:
      - gradle/test:
          app_src_directory: some/folder
```